# Missing clarification in the OCaml manual about unboxed/boxed

Tags: ocaml, manual

The OCaml manual states:

> As another optimization, unboxable record types are represented specially; unboxable record types are the immutable record types that have only one field.

(https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#ss:c-tuples-and-records)

But which *type* can that "one field" have? Only native, or any record type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any type: OCaml memory representation is uniform.

More precisely, in term of memory representation, OCaml values are either integer or pointers to a block.
And a block consists in a header followed by a number of values.

Unboxing replaces the unboxed memory representation of a pointer to a block which contains only one OCaml value by this value.

Comment: So I can have an unboxed record with a field `int list`? Maybe you can add a couple of examples that make sense?

Comment: Yes. The type of the field is irrelevant.